# Customizer related question

Tags: theme-customizer

i am building a theme for WordPress and i have set all the get theme mods and everything works fine.

Now my question is related to the options.
I have a get_the_mod which has a **type=>textarea** in customizer.php but i want to add a **type=>checkbox** also.

I want to write a comditional like
**if the checkbox is selected then show the textarea option otherwise not**
my get_theme_mod is like

```
    <p>
         <?php if (get_theme_mod('footer_tauthor') != ""){
     echo get_theme_mod('footer_tauthor');
 } else {
     echo 'Website Runs on openBlogger by <a href="yo.com">YOyo</a>';
 }?>
            </p>
```

what i can do to make it check box first, then text area if selected by user.
the customizer control is like

```
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control( $wp_customize, 'footer_tauthor',
array(
'label' => 'Update Footer Copyright Text',
'type' => 'textarea',
'section'  => 'site_footer',
'settings' => 'footer_tauthor',
) ) );
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can define the conditional display on definition in PHP with that in the arguments array of `footer_tauthor`

```
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control( $wp_customize, 'footer_tauthor',
    array(
        // other args ...
        "active_callback" => function ($control) {
            return $control->manager->get_setting("checkboxSettingName")->value();
        },
    ) 
) );
```

Comment: will you please elaborate your answer

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: what actually it  does (code) in plain english i mean and also what checkboxsettingname represents

Comment: edit your question to add the whole code that you use for registering the checkbox.